# Forcely Turn on laptop screen backlight

Tags: windows-7, laptop, drivers, backlight

I have a laptop with hybrid graphic card. As it is a bit old (2010) the support for it totally stopped, and i can't install the official AMD graphic card drivers as it complains that for notebook they want special ones, and i should use the ones provided by Acer (dated 2011..)

I recently updated the drivers to 13.12 (i have a HD5470m with a gen1 intel) using leshcatlabs.net ones. They work for almost everything, but when the pc (windows 7) wakes up form sleep (or after i closed the screen) the backlight doesn't turn on. This doesn't happen with the intel card.

Is there a way (a system call, a driver call, a openGL/CL/DX method, a cmd command, a software, a ritual dance, whatever!) which can force the backlight of the laptop screen on?

Comment: What's the laptop exact model?

Comment: Acer aspire 4820TG.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like an issue with the backlight.

I have experienced the similar issue in the pasted were, there are 2 backlights. When one of the back lights fail, the inverter shuts off as there is no longer equal load on the inverter.

When you toggle between the different screen the inverter tries again.

To resolve the problem I suggest you replace the panel or be brave and try to replace the bulb.